# how to get current authenticated user from current session in the freemarker template

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

1.How to get current authenticated user from current session in the freemarker template.

```
<#assign

user = Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal
name = user.getName()
isDenisName = user.isDenis()
>
```

This code does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<#assign 
    known=Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT??>
<#if known>    
    <#assign
        user = Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal
        isDenisName = user.getUsername() == "Denis">
<#else>
    <#assign
        isDenisName=false>
</#if>
```